# Web map server won't connect

Tags: qgis, wms, proxy

I am using QGIS 3.4.2 and trying to access this WMS from the USGS (orthoimagery):
https://raster.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/Orthoimagery/USGS_EROS_Ortho_1Foot/ImageServer/WMSServer

The connection times out and capabilities won't load. Any help? Think it's a proxy server issue? If so, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

That server was deprecated in 2016.

https://www.usgs.gov/news/usgs-national-map-orthoimagery-map-services-transition-and-other-map-service-changes

The official announcement includes links to the replacememt services.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The only thing is the orthoimagery available through the links is low resolution (1m). I'm desperately seeking a way to stream higher resolution orthos through QGIS.

Comment: I'm not an expert on those layers, but when looking at the service pages I recall seeing that even though the services are named "NAIP" which is 1m, they had imagery down to 6" in areas where it was available.